# Using nginx for nagios instead of Apache

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, nginx, nagios

I want to install nagios but instead of using apache i would like to use nginx. I installed nagios-cli and it automatically brings parts of apache which puts a script into `/etc/init.d/apache2` and annoy me on every bootup. I have nginx with php,cgi and mono working fine. But I am unsure how to remove apache from my system

How do I remove apache or not get it included with nagios?
I am using debian squeeze (6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to uninstall apache2 because you don't want to mess with dependencies, you can disable it by doing:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 stop
update-rc.d apache2 disable
```

Then configure nginx to serve nagios (I don't have experience with it to help you)

Answer (score 0):

maybe this howto help:

http://www.nakedmcse.com/Home/tabid/39/forumid/14/threadid/37/scope/posts/Default.aspx

You need be able to execute perl scripts with nginx.